# GetAttribute of WebElement in Selenium Firefox Driver Returns Empty

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, getattribute

So I have a test that was written, and the test runs and works using the `Selenium` `ChromeDriver` just fine. I was tasked with getting the tests working on the `FirefoxDriver` as well.

Part of the test we input text into a login field, and then check the login field to make sure it was input. The way we check the field is like this

```
public virtual string Text => WebElement.GetAttribute("value");
while (!Text.Equals(inputText) && count++ < 3)
```

This works perfectly fine in `Chrome`. However it does not in `Firefox`. When I debug the test, it shows that `Text` is `""` or empty/blank. If I open Firefox, I can do this `document.getElementById("login").value` and it returns the correct value.

Is `WebElement.GetAttribute` implemented differently in the `FirefoxDriver` or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say in your case why is not working on `Firefox`, there is no different implementation between browsers. You can try alternate solution using `IJavascriptExecutor` instead as below :-

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string Text = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].value", WebElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium protocol to get an attribute/property has evolved with Selenium 3.

With Selenium 2, the method `WebElement.GetAttribute(...)` returns the `HTMLElement` property when present and the attribute otherwise.

With Selenium 3, there's a distinctive command to get the property and one for the attribute :
https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-property

In your case it seems that you  are using the geckodriver (Selenium 3) with a client limited to the Selenium 2 specs. It would explain why the property is not returned.

To make it work, you can either upgrade your C# client to V3.0.0-beta2:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/a573338f7f575ccb0069575700f2c059dc94c3b8

Or you can implement your own `GetProperty` in a method extension:

```c#
static string GetProperty(this IWebElement element, string property) {
    var driver = (RemoteWebDriver)((RemoteWebElement)element).WrappedDriver;
    var result = (IList)driver.ExecuteScript(@"
        var element = arguments[0], property = arguments[1];
        if (property in element) return [true, '' + element[property]];
        return [false, 'Missing property: ' + property];
      ", element, property);

    bool succeed = (bool)result[0];
    if (!succeed) throw new WebDriverException((string)result[1]);

    return (string)result[1];
}
```

Usage:

```c#
string value = driver.FindElement(...).GetProperty("value");
```

Comment: This makes sense. I was using geckodriver, and Selenium 3.0 beta2, but Visual Studio kept telling me GetProperty was invalid for some reason, I had to resort to using the Javascript in Saurabh Gaur's post.