# Rselenium - How to scrape all drop down list option values

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, rselenium

How can all the option values from a drop down list be scraped using Rselenium?

Sample of page source:

```
<select name="main$ddArea" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;main$ddArea\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="main_ddArea" class="groupTextBox">
<option selected="selected" value="95182">Area 1</option>
<option value="95183">Area 2</option>
<option value="95184">Area 3</option>
<option value="95185">Area 4</option>
<option value="95186">Area 4</option>
</select>
```

The result wanted is a vector with each value as an element.  For example, values = c("95182", "95183", "95184", "95185", "95186")

Obtaining a string of the values would also likely work as it could be split into elements, e.g., using strsplit.

getElementAttribute() with 'value' or 'option' does not work. E.g.,

```
dd.areas = remDr$findElement(using='id', value="main_ddArea")
dd.areas$getElementAttribute('option')
```

or

```
dd.areas$getElementAttribute('value')
```

`getElementText()` finds one string of the text, e.g, "Area 1 /n Area 2 /n Area 3 /n...." .  But the text can't later be used to navigate the drop down list. In other words, when navigating the dropdown list using `$findelement()`, a value is needed to populate the drop down list; text does not work.

The [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf) does not appear to contain references to drop down lists and neither does the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html#sending-text-to-elements).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rselenium`, but I think you want to find the 'option' elements (as opposed to the `select` element) and get their 'value' attributes.  Try to search for all `option` children of the `select` with ID `main_ddArea` (in your example you have `main$ddArea`?) and then get the 'value' attribute (not the 'option' attribute).

Comment: @mathematical.coffee  Is what you suggest different than what the question indicates was tried by `$getElementAttribute('option')`?  I edited the question to clarify what has been attempted.    If you are suggesting use of a `select` function, my previous research shows that Rselenium does not include the `select` class that other Selenium implementations offer.

Comment: "option" isn't an attribute here, it's a tag, of which you want the "value" attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `findElement` to target the `select` tag then get the `outerHTML` and parse the resulting html:

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_select_tag.htm")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "dropdown")
appHTML <- webElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
doc <- htmlParse(appHTML)
doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")]

> doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")]
[[1]]
[1] "Data Structures"

[[2]]
[1] "Data Mining"
```

There were some recent issues with Firefox and get element attributes which appear when running selenium server 2 with a gecko based browser see [GetAttribute of WebElement in Selenium Firefox Driver Returns Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175190/getattribute-of-webelement-in-selenium-firefox-driver-returns-empty) . In such a case you can use JavaScript to get the attributes

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_select_tag.htm")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "dropdown")
jsScript <- "var element = arguments[0]; return element.outerHTML;"
appHTML <- remDr$executeScript(jsScript, list(webElem))[[1]]
doc <- htmlParse(appHTML)
doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")]

> doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")]
[[1]]
[1] "Data Structures"

[[2]]
[1] "Data Mining"
```

Comment: First, I'll break the rules and say big thanks. You've answered my Rsel questions before and other posts of yours have been very useful.

Comment: But the code does not work for me.  I get  `appHTML <- webElem$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
appHTML
[1] "1"
doc <- htmlParse(appHTML)
Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: '1' 
doc["//option", fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "value")]
list()`                              This is similar to what I get in my code. What's funny is that $getElementText() works.    And $getElementAttribute("name") works.

Comment: There was an issue with firefox and element attributes. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG . It depends what version of firefox and selenium server you are running. As an alternative you can use JavaScript as indicated above.